# Using the Built-in Web server and PhpStorm

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, composer-php, phpstorm

#### Built-in PhpStorm Webserver

---

Working on setting up PhpStorm's built-in server using PhpStorm's [Built-in webserver tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/php-built-in-web-server.html?origin=old_help).

1. Download PHP 5.4.0 or higher. *done*
2. Register the downloaded PHP interpreter in PhpStorm. *done*
3. Open your project. *done*
4. Appoint the PHP 5.4.0 interpreter configuration for use in the project. *done*

Technically the files should then be served at:
`http://localhost:63342/<projectname>/`

**But I am getting this error:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Install dependencies to run this script.' in C:\code\<projectName>\vendor\doctrine\mongodb-odm\tools\sandbox\config.php:9 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\code\<projectName>\vendor\doctrine\mongodb-odm\tools\sandbox\index.php(3): require_once() 
#1 {main} thrown in C:\code\<projectName>\vendor\doctrine\mongodb-odm\tools\sandbox\config.php on line 9
```

--Line 9 is, as one would expect:

```
if (!file_exists($file = __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php')) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Install dependencies to run this script.');
}
```

*This, at first,* made me think that I was missing a dependency file in my php.exe/php.ini.  But after looking in the files a bit I started to think that that might be the wrong track...

--*Then I searched for installing dependencies for doctrine and found this:*

`doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle`

--*Which I then ran using require:*

```
composer require mongodb-odm-bundle
```

This updated the dependency file but did not solve the problem.  I have a feeling that this is something simple that I am missing, but I am either googling the wrong thing or completely ignorant of the path to follow to find the information.

I'm about 800 hours into coding maybe 120 hours into php and 80 hours into PhpStorm.  Let me know if anyone has an idea as to where to start on this problem.  My current method is a bit too shotgun for my tastes.  :)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with composer, but looking at the path to `C:\code\<projectName>\vendor\doctrine\mongodb-odm\tools\sandbox\config.php` it seems like you have too deep a folder structure. That file is checking for `../../vendor/autoload.php` but the `vendor` directory is farther back than that. Did something get installed in a subdirectory that shouldn't have?

Comment: Does anybody knows the default username ad password of the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your dependencies are not installed, try running `composer install` (fixing errors that may or may not pop up) and afterwards your script should be running fine.

For what it's worth `doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle` is not required for ODM to work properly, it's just a bundle to integrate library with Symfony :)

Comment: You were right @malarzm, I had some dependencies that where out of date, actually had to sort through a bit and clean up and then `composer install`.  Thanks.